# Can't centre image in middle if span

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently trying to centre these two images in the centre of the spans they are in however no matter what I do its just not having it! Any help would be appreciated!

The company I'm now working for uses wordpress and I'm very new to it.

[image: Screenshot]

The image linked is the elements that I'm working on.

Comment: We'll need some code to work with, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: HTML at-least ?

Comment: Especially since the image **isn't in a span** in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```css
img.your-class {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<img class="your-class" src="..." alt="...">
```